# Fetch API iterating through objects properties intermittently returns a type error of foreach undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Hello am a beginner JS student. I'm using the fetch api to iterate through the properties of the requested object. My problem is that I intermittently get an error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. Anyone know why foreach will run sometimes and sometimes return an undefined error? Is this due to the API, server or the code?
Is this a common thing when working with API/servers?

This is the specific error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Appreciate all advice!

```
function listBookItems(e){
e.preventDefault();
let keyListBookItems = document.getElementById("view-catalog-id").value;
let crudSelect = '&op=select';
let titleOutput = document.getElementById("title-output-id");
doRecursiveRequest(url + qs + keyListBookItems + crudSelect)
    .then(obj => obj.data.forEach((el) => {
        titleOutput.innerHTML += "<label class=\"form-control\" id=\"exampleTextarea\" rows=\"12\" style=\"margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px; height: 115px;\"><span id='output-span'>" +
            "Title: " + el.title + "<br>" + " Author: " + el.author + "<br>" + "id: " + el.id
            + "<br>" + "Last updated: " + el.updated + "<span></label>";
    .catch((err) => titleOutput.innerHTML = err);
```

Comment: `obj.data` is undefined. What is exactly `obj.data`, and where does it come from?

Comment: {status: "success", data: Array(1)}
data: [{…}]
status: "success"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

you can make a debugging to check the 'obj.data'.

Comment: This answer might be correct, but you will have to instruct on how to set debugging to check obj.data for the answer potential to be of maximum benefit.